# What is the order of execution of $http interceptors in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I registered several HTTP interceptors in angular.js app:

```
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
    return {
      request: function(config) {
        console.log("interceptor A request");
        return config;
      },
      response: function(res) {
        console.log("interceptor A response");
        return res;
      }
    };
  });
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(...); // interceptor B with similar code
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(...); // interceptor C with similar code
```

In which order will they be executed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that the interceptors are executed:

- in **registration order** for requests
- in **reverse registration order** for responses

Log:

```
interceptor A request
interceptor B request
interceptor C request
(request happens here)
interceptor C response
interceptor B response
interceptor A response
```

Comment: Your understanding is right. Refer the link: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/03/angular-http-interceptors-source/